# Detect if the middle of a div have been reached

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-waypoints

Can I launch some code in Javascript once the viewport reaches a specific height inside a div?

I calculate 25%, 50%, 75% and 100% of the div's height using this piece of code:

```
var contenido = ".my-div";

//Show div height
console.log($(contenido).height());

//Show div height (25%)
console.log(Math.round($(contenido).height()/4));

//Show div height (50%)
console.log(Math.round($(contenido).height()/2));

//Show div height (75%)
console.log(Math.round($(contenido).height()-($(contenido).height()/4)));
```

*Forget about the console.log, I just use it to show that the heigths are calculated.*

I know that you can make it for the whole page using:

```
$(window).scroll(function() {
    if ($(window).scrollTop()  > $(window).height() / 2)
    {
       //code
    }
});
```

I wonder if something similar can be done with specific elements.

I tried using waypoints, but somehow I don't really understand the offset part, or at least it doesn't make what I expect.

Answer (score 0):

Somehow I understood how you can make it with Waypoints (sometimes it is really difficult to understand so technical docs if English is not your mother language)

```
var venticincopor = -Math.abs($(contenido).height()/4);


$(contenido).waypoint(function() {

    console.log("25%");

}, { offset: venticincopor, triggerOnce: true });
```